# nested forms not working with has_one association and fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I have 2 models:

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :buyer_info
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buyer_info
end
```

Model `BuyerInfo`

```
class BuyerInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer
end
```

In controller (I use devise to create buyer `/buyers/registrations_controller`)

```
class Buyers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    resource.build_buyer_info
  end
end
```

In _form `registrations/_form`

```
<div class="">
  <div class="mid">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :full_name, :placeholder => "YOUR NAME", :class => "form-control"%>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "EMAIL ADDRESS", :class => "form-control", :class => "form-control"%>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "PHONE NUMBER", :class => "form-control"%>
      <br/> <br/>

      <%= f.fields_for :buyer_info do |buyer_info| %>
        <%= buyer_info.text_field :email_receive1, :placeholder => "SEND MY LEADS TO EMAIL #1 ", :class => "form-control"%>
        <%= buyer_info.text_field :email_receive2, :placeholder => "SEND MY LEADS TO EMAIL #2 ", :class => "form-control"%>
        <%= buyer_info.text_field :email_receive3, :placeholder => "SEND MY LEADS TO EMAIL #3 ", :class => "form-control"%>
        <%= buyer_info.text_field :email_receive4, :placeholder => "SEND MY LEADS TO EMAIL #4 ", :class => "form-control"%>  
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Comment", :type => :image, :src => "#{asset_url(@source_folder+'signup-button.png')}" %>

    <% end %>       
  </div>           
</div>
```

When I run code, in view only display text_fields full_name, email, phone. it dont display fields in fields_for.

How to display fields in fields_for when created model uses nested model has_one relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Buyers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    build_resource({})
    @buyer_info = resource.build_buyer_info
  end
end
```

Try this